# Should I convert JSON to Array to be able to iterate it with v-for?

Tags: json, vue.js

In the following code I am getting data from server and filling array with them:

```
   Vue.http.post('/dbdata', DataBody).then((response) => {
      App.$refs.userContent.rasters_previews_list.$set(response); // putting JSON answer to Component data in userContent
      console.log("App.$refs.userContent.rasters_previews_list: ", App.$refs.userContent.rasters_previews_list.length);

      }, (response) => {
          console.log("Error")
      });
```

Now I am filling. `data` is declared in `var userContent = Vue.extend({`. I am using `App.$refs.userContent.rasters_previews_list` to `set` it's value, because one man from SO said that there is no other way to get access to constructor. I tried to do output of `rasters_previews_list` after changing with `watch`, but here is what I am see. http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/08/04/57a326e39c1a4.png I really do not understand am I setting it's right way or no. If yes, why I do not see data and see only this crap?

```
    data: function ()  {
      return {
        rasters_previews_list: []
      }
}
```

But How I can iterate it with `v-for`?

```
<ul v-for="img in rasters_previews_list">
<li>{{img}}</li>
<ul>
```

This code is display one bullet. So it's look like it's assume that there is one `object`.

My object in browser console look like:
`Object {request: Object, data: Array[10], status: 200, statusText: "OK", ok: true}`

Answer (score 1):

Your setting the full response instead of just the data you actually need.

```js
Vue.http.post('/dbdata', DataBody).then((response) => {
  App.$refs.userContent.rasters_previews_list.$set(response.data);
  console.log("App.$refs.userContent.rasters_previews_list: ", App.$refs.userContent.rasters_previews_list.length);
}, (response) => {
  console.log("Error")
});
```

If this isn't what you are looking for please post a full example.